# How do drugs enter synapses?

Tags: pharmacology, neurophysiology

Many psychopharmaceutical drugs change synapse chemistry or directly agonize neuroreceptors in the brain. For example, cabergoline is a D<sub>2</sub> agonist.

How do these compounds enter the physical synapses? Are they simply lipid soluble and diffuse throughout all cells?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that cabergoline does not need to enter a cell in order to function.

Cabergoline (as well as most (possibly all?) other drugs that target synapses) interact with proteins on the surfaces of the synapses. For example, the [D2 receptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dopamine_receptor_D2) that you mention is a dopamine receptor which in its active form is expressed on the surface of neurons near the synaptic cleft.